# How can i remove stains from images using python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am making a script that removes spots from scanned images like noise and contrast, but right now I want to remove stains from images but what is a good way to handle this?

this is an example of an image i want to remove the stain from:
[image: This is an example of an image I want to remove the stain from]

i want to remove the stain but without losing too much image details because i need to be able to see the lines and text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the imag only has black and white colors, you could try to binarize it. There are many ways to do this, but the *scikit-image* package has an option to see the results of applying several thresholdings:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
from skimage.filters import try_all_threshold

img = io.imread('your_img')

fig, ax = try_all_threshold(img, figsize=(10, 8), verbose=False)
plt.show()
```

EDIT: binarization only works on grayscale images, so you should convert your image to B&W:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
from skimage.filters import try_all_threshold
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

img = io.imread('your_img')
img = rgb2gray(img)

fig, ax = try_all_threshold(img, figsize=(15, 15), verbose=False)
plt.show()
```

The result is attached here.

Of course you can also try to apply your own threshold. It would be nice to check the histogram of the image to see an optimum value for thresholding.

[image: Result of several binarizations]